# Call a PHP non-static member function from XSLT

Tags: php, xslt

In PHP, you can use `XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions()` to allow calling PHP functions from within the XSLT code, like this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="php:function('myfunc', 'param1')/*" />
```

You can also call static member functions on objects with `::` notation:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="php:function('myclass::myfunc', 'param1')/*" />
```

However I would like to call a non-static function, belonging to the class that started the XSLT transform.

How can I use `php:function` in XSLT to call a non-static member function on a PHP object?

(By which I mean how do I specify the object in XSLT, and what syntax do I use to indicate I want to call a member function of that object.)

Solutions that don't rely on global variables would be preferred!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've worked this one out, but it's a bit dodgy.  Other answers welcome.

Take this example class:

```php
class Example {
    protected $greet;
    public function __construct($g) {
        $this->greet = $g;
    }
    public function greeting($name) {
        return $this->greet . ' ' . $name;
    }
}
```

Then you will need these helper functions:

```php
// Serialise the object and replace ASCII null characters with @NULL@
function xsltSerialize($object)
{
    return str_replace("\0", '@NULL@', serialize($object));
}

// Unserialise $object (of type $className) and call $func
function callMember($className, $object, $func, $param)
{
    $rf = new ReflectionMethod($className, $func);
    $o = unserialize(str_replace('@NULL@', "\0", $object));
    return $rf->invoke($o, $param);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```php
// This is the object that will get called from within the XSL.  Note
// that we are passing a parameter to the constructor which gets saved
// in the object instance, so we will know later whether we have the
// original object back again.
$e = new Example('Hello');

// Pass the object to the XSL code, after serialising it
$xsl->setParameter('', 'obj', xsltSerialize($e));
```

Then in the XSLT, call the PHP `callMember()` function, supplying the original name of the class, the serialised object, the function to call, and a parameter to that function.

```xsl
Output is
<xsl:value-of select="php:function('callMember', 'Example', $obj, 'greeting', 'everyone')"/>
```

The end result is that the member function is called on the correct instance of the object:

```
Output is Hello everyone
```

The word "Hello" shows that the value set in the constructor outside the XSLT was preserved, and "everyone" shows that the parameter passed in from XSLT made it through as well.

There are a number of shortcomings with this method:

1. Serialising and then unserialising is quite wasteful of resources and will impact performance if it's done too many times or on a large object.
2. Not all objects can be serialised.
3. Only a fixed number of parameters can be passed to the function, so you'll need different versions of `callMember()` for different numbers of parameters.
4. Because of the serialisation process, the XSLT call will be operating on a copy of the object, not the original.  So any changes you make to the object will be lost once the function returns.  (The state won't even be preserved between two XSLT calls to the same object.)